How to create custom HTML attibutes on a dash app (to implement UIKit framework)
I am working on a Dash/plotly app styled with UIKit. Turns out I want to use the sticky feature of UIKit which requires a custom attribute like this:
<div uk-sticky></div>

I tried using a custom js file in assets/ to add the attribute like this:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var stickyDiv = document.querySelector('.my-sticky-div');
        if (stickyDiv) {
                    stickyDiv.setAttribute('uk-sticky', '');
        }
});


The app code goes like this:
import dash
from dash import html

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div('This is a sticky div', className='my-sticky-div')
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)


When I run it, I can see the js code is there, but the div only has the class. The attibute uk-sticky never showed up and the style was not applied.
I also tried adding the script via html.Script but it is the same. How can I do this?

is this custom js file loaded ?
